# How to create a folder in my computer when saving screenshots using Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I want to create folder when saving screenshots using Puppeteer.

My problem is I need to save multiple screenshots in different folders, so every time I need to create specific folders in my computer manually, and than do the save screenshots action using Puppeteer page.screenshot path. Otherwise it will show my the error that can't find the path.

Here is my script:

```js
TestManager.prototype.takeScreenshot = async function(waitEle, page, lang, appName, module, featureName = false, number = false){
    let Path = './screenshots/' + lang + '/' + module + '/';
    let screenshotName = Path + appName + '_' + module + ((featureName === false) ? '' : ('_' + featureName)) + ((number === false) ? '' : ('_' + number)) + '.png';

    if(waitEle){
        await page.screenshot({path: screenshotName, fullPage: true});
    }
    console.log("capture screenshot " + screenshotName);
};
```

I want to add a script in my function, the logic is if the path can't be found, create a new folder. E.g. exist folder with correct lang, but doesn't exist folder with correct module, I want to create a module which name is the same to the parameter value of module in my computer path.

Answer (score 3):

You should pre-create directories using [`fs.mkdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Andrey, I can now use it successfully.